Issue Creating Virtual Environment in Python 3.9.13 on Windows
I'm encountering an issue while creating a virtual environment in Python 3.9.13 on Windows. When I run the command:
python -m venv myenv

I receive the following error:
Error: Command '['D:\\django\\myenv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.

Steps I've Taken:

Reinstalled Python 3.9.13 to ensure a clean setup.
Verified Python is correctly installed and accessible in my PATH.

Despite these steps, the issue persists. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Environment Details:

Operating System: Windows
Python Version: 3.9.13

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I would suggest trying to reinstall pip. Also, since it is Windows, running as administrator might solve the problem too.
